# Meteor.js: nemo64:bootstrap or bower bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bower

Given that we're living in a post Meteor 1.0 world, is it "better" to use the meteor package nemo64:bootstrap or to install the bower (meteor package) and then manage bootstrap as a bower dependency?

I feel like if I were going to start from frontend scratch I would use nemo64:bootstrap, but if I have a prepackaged frontend with a million packages loaded up already, with working dependency trees, I should manage dependencies through bower?

Using the mquandalle (https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower) package to minify all my bower assets, it re-installs jquery! Doubling up on that can't be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company has begun converting some of our bower dependencies to Meteor packages. We do this because you can not publish your own Meteor packages if they require bower dependencies.

*Sidenote: We use nemo64:bootstrap and it works very well for us.*

Answer (score 0):

The particular situation I was concerned with was 'porting' a pre-designed template to meteor.

I settled on `twbs:bootstrap` because it was a one step addition; `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` can be done and undone easily (in source control)! Bootstrap also guarantees it because its official, and load order is sorted!!

To deal with all the bower dependencies, I just included them in the head, and then used

```
Template.sidebar.rendered = function() {
   // ..initialise all the libraries here
}
```

Which has the luckiest feature of only initialising the libraries when the actual template is loaded!!! Yay

I think you can even use `miro:preloaded` or equivalent to conditionally load those js libraries (rather than using `/public` and serving static js assets from `<head>`)